# I would like to move the scrol product selector to the right or left from the text box woocommerce wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, selector, product

[image]

I have this problem and I hope you guys can help me out. as you can see in the image the qty srol selector its in front of the qty information. this its a problem because you can not see how many qty`s your are placing order. can you help me out to fix this problem. for wordpress im using woocommerce.

Maybe you can give me a css to put in the css personalize section to fix this issue.

Comment: How do we see that from your image? And why don't you change the CSS (which you haven't even shared) properly?

Comment: How do you expect one provide a css fix without you proving any code ? Please read [ask] and [mcve] page and edit your question

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply, Im apologize to not put the right information. I have not enough experience at this area. Im using the following css:                                                                                        
    .scrollup {
    background: rgba(181, 208, 61, 0.5) none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border-radius: 5px;
    bottom: 20px;
    color: #ffffff;
    display: block;
    font-size: 20px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 35px;
    position: fixed;
    right: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 40px;
    z-index: 99;
}

Comment: and using this in the image that I upload the product selector its in the middle, so if you press + or - the qty it puts behind the selector making hard to see how much qty of product you are adding to the cart to purchase. for an example if you can check it out directly in the web page https://suplestar.com/shop-2/aminoacidos/gat-bcaas-180-capsulas/   this link goes directly to this issue.

Comment: I highly appreciate your attention.